# STEP_COUNTER and STEP_DETECTOR works with SDK 28, but not SDK 29?

Tags: android, sdk, sensors, sensormanager

I've made a service that regularly broadcasts counted steps from both the STEP_COUNTER and STEP_DETECTOR sensor. In one app I made it worked flawlessly, but after copying the exact same code to another project it stopped working. After hours of debugging, I figured out how to solve it. When I change the compileSdkVersion in the build.gradle to 28 it works fine, but changing it to 29 makes it stop working. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Privacy changes in Android 10](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#physical-activity-recognition) (which apply to apps that have a `targetSdkVersion` of 29 or higher):

> Android 10 introduces the [`android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION) runtime permission for apps that need to detect the user's step count or classify the user's physical activity, such as walking, biking, or moving in a vehicle. This is designed to give users visibility of how device sensor data is used in Settings.

> The only built-in sensors on the device that require you to declare this permission are the [step counter](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion#sensors-motion-stepcounter) and [step detector](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion#sensors-motion-stepdetector) sensors.

Therefore you must:

1. Add the `android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION` to your app's manifest.
2. Request the permission at runtime and have the user grant that permission.

Comment: I already did the first step. Step two is supposed to be a pop-up at runtime right?

Comment: I didn't get the request at runtime, but after changing it manually it worked. Thanks.